# cannot connect to to database (netbeans, MAMP, Workbench)

Tags: mysql, macos, netbeans, mamp-pro

I am having serious trouble connecting to MySQL server and I do not know why, I am trying to configure a netbeans project I am using MAMP, workbench and netbeans. I have configured MAMP so my Apache server runs on port 80 and MySQL to port to 3306, i have then configured workbench to work on port 3306, i have imported my netbeans project database to workbench, the database is present and connected to MyPHPAdmin, i have put the netbeans project in my 'MAMP/htdocs'folder, netbeans can see my project and is connecting to it but is not connecting to my database and I just cant figure out why, this is on an OSX machine, (I have also read posts about not using TCP/IP connection on workbench and to use local socket/pipe but that does not seem to work for me either, anyway I seem to be establishing a successful connection through TCP/IP...) [Configuration setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QteYt.jpg)

Comment: Did you set MySQL password in PHP code (database connection part)?

Comment: I literally just figured it out 5 minutes ago..... that was exactly it... i'm fit to kill myself........ new to php and full stack....... the machine I was using has no password.... mine machine does...

Comment: Glad to here that. Happy coding.